# Android open default gallery with specific folder link cannot be loaded

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-sdcard, image-gallery

I am trying to open the folder containing captured photos by default-Gallery in Android .

But after opening it, it shows "cannot be load"  at the screen  of the Gallery.

Would you please tell me is there amything missing to pass the intent ?

The below is my code

```
public void buttonGallery(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(resultPhoto.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

...

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "NBA_FINAL_photo");
        resultPhoto = mediaStorageDir;
```

Comment: Raju: Have you found any solution for this problem. If yes, could you please share it with others. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget set Permisson in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: still cannot load the pictures with default gallery. but thanks.

Comment: try intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Answer (score 0):

you have to add "file://" into Uri

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + resultPhoto.getAbsolutePath(), "image/*");
```